# How do I receive OnActivate/OnDeactivate calls for my Caliburn.Micro windows?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

After I have shown a `Window` like this...

```
IoC.Get(Of IWindowManager).ShowWindow(vm, , settings)
```

...the ViewModel (`vm`) never gets activated/deactivated with the `Window`. It just always stays active even when I open another `Window` and another and another.

I've tried adding the ViewModel to my root view which is a `Conductor(Of IScreen).Collection.OneActive` and doing the (de)activation myself but it seems a weird construction to me and I'm having trouble to get it to behave.

How *am* I supposed to do this?

Comment: If the parent is not active, the child will not be active either even when `ActivateItem` is called.

Comment: It *is* active but it never becomes deactivated when I switch to another window. Also Caliburn's `CloseStrategy` doesn't account for windows because windows are not children of a regular `Conductor`. There's a separate `WindowConductor` included with the `WindowManager` but it doesn't have a customizable `CloseStrategy` and it doesn't play with the application `CloseStrategy`. :-(